# Confusion Regarding definition of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

Physically, the electric field is defined as:

> the force per unit charge that would be exerted on a test charge.

What is confusing me here is what exactly is meant by

> per unit charge

If the definition of electric field was defined as

> The force that a test charge (of any magnitude) would experience when placed at a particular point in the field.

would make much more sense to me, but I feel I am misunderstanding something, as I do not understand the significance of:

> per unit charge

Comment: If you only have fixed point charges, then you can choose any charge of any magnitude as the test charge. However, if you have dielectrics and/or conductors, the test charge will also disturb the system, so that the force felt by the test charge will be different from the electric field. You actually are supposed to take the limit as the test charge's magnitude goes to zero, so that its disturbance on the system goes to zero faster. That is why you have to divide by the test charge's magnitude and take the limit to zero test charge magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is the "test" (also "fiducial") charge is supposed to not distort the field. Imagine defining Newtonian gravity of the Earth as "the force on supermassive blackhole Sag A* divided by 8.54$\times 10^{36}\,$kg.  It's just not a good way to abstract.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we have a positive point charge with charge $Q$ at the origin, then we put a test charge with charge $q$ at distance $r$ from the positive charge.

Then the force on the test charge is
$$
\vec{F} = \frac{kQq}{r^2} \hat{e}_r
$$
where $\hat{e}_r$ is a unit vector pointing from the $Q$ to the test charge.

Note that $F$ depends on the test charge $q$. Therefore, your proposed definition:

> The force that a test charge (of any magnitude) would experience when placed at a particular point in the field.

does not make sense, since test charges of different magnitudes would experience different forces.

The idea of the electric field is to look at the part of the force on the test charge that does not depend on the test charge itself. Therefore:
$$
\vec{E} = \frac{\vec{F}}{q} = \frac{kQ}{r^2} \hat{e}_r
$$
Saying "per unit charge" is another way of saying "divide the force, which is proportional to $q$, by $q$". Another way to say it is that $\vec{E}$ would be the force if $q=1$ (in whatever units we are working in) -- every "unit" of charge contributes $\vec{E}$ to the force, so $n$ units of charge ($q=n$) would lead to a force $n\vec{E}$.

Finally, a small subtlety, but technically we also want to look at the limit that $q$ is small, to avoid having to think about the test charge changing the distribution of charges creating the field we are measuring.